# Restrict access in wp-admin area?

Tags: wp-admin

What action or filter do I have to check or compare against $pagenow?

In the admin area, I need to let non admin and editor users only to access:

```
index.php (dashboard)
upload.php (attachments management)
media.php (attachments management)
media-new.php (attachments management)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that depends on if you want to redirect users away the you should use `init` hook since no output or headers are sent before that hook. or if you want to display a nice "You Don't have the right permissions to access this page" message then you can use the `wp_head` action hook:

```
//display meassage
add_action('admin_head','my_restrict_access');
function my_restrict_access_meassage(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow == 'upload.php' && !current_user_can( 'upload_files' )){
        echo '<div class="wrap"><br />
            <div id="message" class="error">You Dont have the right permissions to access this page</div>
        </div>';
        exit();
    }
}
//or redirect
add_action('init','my_restrict_redirect');
function my_restrict_redirect(){
    global $pagenow;
    if (!is_admin())
        return '';
    if ($pagenow == 'upload.php' && !current_user_can( 'upload_files' )){
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose Members plugin. It allows you to create new user groups and define their access to each and almost every page in wp-admin. You can find it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/